# JavaScript sorting with replace

Tags: javascript

I'm a little stuck at one place, and it's bugging me whole day.

I have this code:

```
function main() {
    function sort(a, b){
        return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text());    
    }

    var title = $(".topictitle").sort(sort).text();
    $('body').append(title)
}
```

I want to be able to replace the text for each element (I mean I would like to replace the '.' and 'Link: ' before every element with '' nothing) and add a break tag after each one and post it in the end of the document on separate line. 
The few ways I tried didn't work.
Any ideas?

The HTML:

```
<table class="tablebg" width="100%" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
                <a title="Публикувано на: Чет Сеп 01, 2011 11:40 am" href="./viewtopic.php?f=70&amp;t=61127" class="topictitle">]Link: The Sid Movie (CS) [Replay]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
                 <a title="Публикувано на: Чет Фев 24, 2011 11:29 am" href="./viewtopic.php?f=70&amp;t=57832" class="topictitle">Link: Project Team 9 (CS) [Replay]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
                <a title="Публикувано на: Чет Сеп 01, 2011 11:30 am" href="./viewtopic.php?f=70&amp;t=61127" class="topictitle">Link: Guilty Gear Freaks</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
                 <a title="Публикувано на: Чет Фев 24, 2011 11:51 am" href="./viewtopic.php?f=70&amp;t=57874" class="topictitle">Link: Counter Strike 1.6 [GMV]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
                <a title="Публикувано на: Чет Сеп 01, 2011 11:42 am" href="./viewtopic.php?f=70&amp;t=61127" class="topictitle">Link: C&C: Generals Zero Hour [GMV]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="row1">
                 <a title="Публикувано на: Чет Фев 24, 2011 11:59 am" href="./viewtopic.php?f=70&amp;t=57874" class="topictitle">Link: King of Fighters [Replay]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I would like to get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAz5R.jpg but sorted.

The unnecessary characters are things like "Link:", "[" "]" and so on..

There is no need for click, it should load at the bottom of the page when it's loaded (no fancy stuff, just need it to execute when the page loads and when I'm ready I can just remove the script).

The final HTML is just a list without tags or anything:

```
<html lang="bg" xml:lang="bg" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body class="ltr">
[url=http://forum.website.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=10266]The Sid Movie (CS) [Replay][/url]
<br>
[url=http://forum.website.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=10265]Project Team 9 (CS) [Replay][/url]
<br>
[url=http://forum.website.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=9720]Guilty Gear Freaks[/url]
<br>
[url=http://forum.website.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=9232]Counter Strike 1.6 [GMV][/url]
<br>
[url=http://forum.website.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=9258]C&C: Generals Zero Hour [GMV][/url]
<br>
[url=http://forum.website.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=6581]King of Fighters [Replay][/url]
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

I just need to be able to copy/paste the list directly to a topic afterwards, the script will be loaded through Greasemonkey and it will load only for this purpose, if it's not need it will be disabled.

The code I was using was this one:

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function main() {
    $('.topictitle').each(function(){
      var text = '[url=' + 'http://forum.website.com' + $(this).attr('href').replace('.','') + ']' + $(this).text().replace('Link: ','') + "[/url]<br/>"
      $('body').append(text)
  })
}

addJQuery(main);
```

That's pretty much what I want, but it needs to be sorted...

Comment: Can you show some sample *input* html and some *output* html (what you'd like it to look like *after* it's been processed/sorted)? I'm confused by what your code's meant to be doing.

Comment: The thing is I have a big list with anchor tags.
I would like to be able to take their text and sort it alphabetically, then replace the unnecessary characters.
The purpose is to be able to make a phpbb catalogue with sorted elements, without going manual trought all the topics.

Html:

    <tr>
        <td>
         <a title="Posted at: June 22, 2011 1:53 pm" href="./viewtopic.php?f=70&amp;t=59900" class="topictitle">Title1</a>
        </td>
    </tr> And the same thing for all other elements.

Comment: Great; that doesn't really help. Please add a sample of some of the HTML (enough to give a picture of what you're working with), and how you'd like those samples to be changed to show what you want to end up with, into your question (click the 'edit' link below the tags). Also: what are 'unnecessary characters'?

Comment: Please, show the HTML you want to end up with (based on the sample you've posted in your question); your image doesn't seem to have anything in common with the HTML you posted. I'm sorry if I appear over-bearing, but I'm trying to work out how to help, and currently there isn't enough information available to do anything other than guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/xKUND/2/) looks like what you need.  First you sort, then you iterate with `.each`

Comment: I see that you are a new user.  If this is the correct answer, click that little hollow checkbox on the left to select this as the correct answer.